# Get the parameters of a drawn circle over an ImageWidget

Tags: python-2.7, mouseevent, pyqt4, qt-designer

I'm trying, like I said in the title, to get the parameters of a circle drawn with guiqwt.tools.CircleTool. I add that tool to the ImageWidget I create, and when you click over the widget, the circle it's drawn. But, as I want to get the coordinates, I have to extend the ImageWidget class so that when the left button it's released, a signal is emitted, in order to connect to a function where it's done all the stuff.

That's the extended class:

```
class ExtendedImageWidget(ImageWidget):
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'))
```

The code to connect with the function:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.imagewidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.selection_tools)
```

And finally the function:

```
    def selection_tools(self):    
        print('inside selection_tools')        
        if self.selectCircle.action.isChecked()==True:
            print('inside selectCircle')
            tamListaItems=len(self.imagewidget.plot.items)
            self.circulo=self.imagewidget.plot.items[tamListaItems-1]
            #Remove any item other than an image or the grid
            for i in range(1,tamListaItems)[::-1]:
                if type(self.imagewidget.plot.items[i]) !=   type(self.imagewidget.plot.items[1]):
                          self.imagewidget.plot.del_item(self.imagewidget.plot.items[i])
            #Add the last item drawn
            self.imagewidget.plot.add_item(self.circulo, autoscale=False)
            self.imagewidget.plot.replot()
            #Get and print some parameters
            circle=self.selectCircle.get_final_shape()
            print('circle',circle)
            self.center=circle.get_center()
            ptsDiameter=circle.get_xdiameter()
            print('center',self.center)
            print('ptsDiameter',ptsDiameter)
            self.radius=np.int(np.round((np.sqrt(np.square(ptsDiameter[0]-ptsDiameter[2]) + np.square(ptsDiameter[1]-ptsDiameter[3])))/2))
            print('radius',self.radius)
```

The issue is that, the first circle I draw (It is drawn, and detected as an item in the ItemList), I got nothing at the output. The second I draw, I get the parameters of the previous circle. Here and example of the output I get:

```
    inside selection_tools
    inside selectCircle
    ('circle', <guiqwt.shapes.EllipseShape object at 0x0C6AA978>)
    ('center', (106.88683969465652, 148.08916030534348))
    ('ptsDiameter', (64.703511450381697, 101.00079389312975, 149.07016793893132, 195.17752671755721))
    ('radius', 63)
    inside selection_tools
```

If I change:

```
circle=self.selectCircle.get_last_final_shape()
```

by:

```
circle=self.selectCircle.get_final_shape()
```

The signals seems to be working well, because when I draw a circle, I instantaneously get printed the notifications "inside selection_tools" and "inside selectCircle", but it doesn't return to any parameter.

If someone could help me it would be great.
Thanks in advance.